# App is not opened by deep link in Android browser

Tags: android

I defined intent filter for `ResultPayActivity` in manifest as shown below:

```
<activity android:name=".ResultPayActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sanduqcheh"  />
</intent-filter>
```

package of my app is: `com.example.pegah_system.sanduqchehproject`. This app has already been installed.

Now I want to call app in browser by this deep link:

`intent://1#Intent;scheme=sanduqcheh;package=com.example.pegah_system.sanduqchehproject;end`

But when I call in the browser App can not be executed, and URL is searched on Google.com.

I have read other questions about this, but my problem was not resolved.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.
The browser can not Run the deep link directly.
for example,you can run a html file like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<a href="intent://123#Intent;scheme=sanduqcheh;package=com.example.pegah_system.sanduqchehproject;end">Click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. But I have two questions here: 1. how can link it to a specific path? 2. How can open the deep link from a server side like expressjs using a res.redirect?

Answer (score 7):

I think this is worth mentioning:

> Deep links will not open your app if you *type* the link on your browser. You must *click* on the link in order to launch your app

I wasted almost an hour trying to debug a perfectly fine code and later found that the problem was with me typing in the link the whole time!